# Hooking sys_execve() on Linux 3.x

Tags: c, operating-system, linux-kernel, exec

I'm trying to hook the `sys_execve()` function on the Linux 3.x kernel by modifying the system call table. The problem is that `sys_execve()` is only supposed to return an error code if execution is unsuccessful. With the wrapper function that I'm using (see below), when `sys_execve()` is called on a valid executable, it executes fine and everything works out. However, when it's called on a nonexistent file or something else that causes an error condition, the calling program will crash with:

```
segfault at 3b ip 000000000000003b...
```

Using `strace` to examine the return value from the hooked `sys_execve()` shows -1 or `ENOSYS` instead of the correct error code, which confuses me since I've checked the assembly of my wrapper function as well as the Linux source code for `sys_execve()`. Any suggestions on why my wrapper isn't properly passing the error code?

```
asmlinkage long new_execve(const char* name, const char const** argv, const char const** envp, struct pt_regs* regs) {
    return orig_func(name, argv, envp, regs);
}
```

Comment: It might be not relevant but I am interested in replacing a system call in linux >3. Could you provide me some information regarding that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hook `execve` by modifying the system call table in a such a way as on `x86_64` the `sys_execve` is called from the `stub_execve`. So the call chain is `sys_call_table[NR_execve] -> stub_execve -> sys_execve -> do_execve` ... Take a look at [stub_execve](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.9/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S#L710) on LXR.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, hooking syscalls in the Linux kernel was an easier task, however, in newer kernels, assembly stubs were added to the syscalls. In order to solve this problem, I patch the kernel's memory on the fly.

You can view my full solution for hooking sys_execve here: https://github.com/kfiros/execmon