# sys_execve hooking on 3.5 kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, hook, system-calls, execve

I am trying to hook sys_execve syscall in Linux kernel v3.5 on x86_32. I simply change sys_call_table entry address to my hook function

```
asmlinkage long (*real_execve)( const char __user*, const char __user* const __user*,
                 const char __user* const __user* );
...
asmlinkage long hook_execve( const char __user* filename, const char __user* const __user* argv,
                    const char __user* const __user* envp )
{
    printk( "Called execve hook\n" );
    return real_execve( filename, argv, envp );
}
...
real_execve = (void*)sys_call_table[ __NR_execve ];
sys_call_table[ __NR_execve ] = (unsigned long)hook_execve;
```

I do set page permission for modifying sys_call_table entries, and mentioned scheme works well for another syscalls (chdir, mkdir and so on). But on execve hooking i got null pointer dereference:

```
Mar 11 14:18:08 mbz-debian kernel: [ 5590.596033] Called execve hook
Mar 11 14:18:08 mbz-debian kernel: [ 5590.596408] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at   (null)
Mar 11 14:18:08 mbz-debian kernel: [ 5590.596486] IP: [<  (null)>]   (null)
Mar 11 14:18:08 mbz-debian kernel: [ 5590.596526] *pdpt = 0000000032302001 *pde = 0000000000000000 
Mar 11 14:18:08 mbz-debian kernel: [ 5590.596584] Oops: 0010 [#1] SMP
```

I call sys_execve with three parameters because of `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S`, that contains `PTREGSCALL3(execve)`. However, i've tried calling it with four parameters (adding `struct pt_regs*`) but i got the same error. Maybe something is totally wrong with this approach to execve? Or did i miss something?

**UPDATE #1**

I found that `sys_call_table[ __NR_execve ]` actually contains address of `ptregs_execve` (not `sys_execve`). It is defined as follows in `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S`:

```
#define PTREGSCALL3(name) \
ENTRY(ptregs_##name) ; \
CFI_STARTPROC; \
leal 4(%esp),%eax; \
pushl_cfi %eax; \
movl PT_EDX(%eax),%ecx; \
movl PT_ECX(%eax),%edx; \
movl PT_EBX(%eax),%eax; \
call sys_##name; \
addl $4,%esp; \
CFI_ADJUST_CFA_OFFSET -4; \
ret; \
CFI_ENDPROC; \
ENDPROC(ptregs_##name)
...
PTREGSCALL3(execve)
```

So in order to modify `sys_execve` i need to replace its code without modifying its address? I have read something similar [here](http://cormander.com/2011/12/how-to-hook-into-hijack-linux-kernel-functions-via-lkm/), is this the way to go?

**UPDATE #2**

Actually i found following call sequence: `do_execve->do_execve_common->search_binary_handler->security_bprm_check`, and this `security_bprm_check` is a wrapper around LSM(Linux Security Module) operation, that controls execution of a binary. After that i've read and followed [this link](http://cormander.com/2012/05/hijacking-linux-kernel-pointers/) and i got it working. It solves my problem as now i can see the name of process to be executed, but i am still unsure about correctness of it. Maybe someone else will add some clarity about all this stuff.

Comment: This post explains why you can't hook `sys_execve` via the `sys_call_table` modification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372912/hooking-sys-execve-on-linux-3-x/9672512#9672512

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov so I've did a working hook on sys_execve via sys_call_table on 3.18, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @kagali-san Please, run the following command on your system `sudo grep stub_execve /proc/kallsyms` ?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, hooking syscalls in the Linux kernel was an easier task, however, in newer kernels, assembly stubs were added to the syscalls. In order to solve this problem, I patch the kernel's memory on the fly.

You can view my full solution for hooking sys_execve here: 
https://github.com/kfiros/execmon